# Prove that if $10 \mid (a^2+ab+b^2)$, then $1000 \mid (a^3-b^3)$.

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers. Prove that if $10 \mid (a^2+ab+b^2)$, then $1000 \mid (a^3-b^3)$.

I saw that $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and $(a^2+ab+b^2) = (a+b)^2-ab$. How can we use the fact that $10 \mid (a^2+ab+b^2)$ to solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$10 \mid (a^2+ab+b^2)$ implies $10 \mid a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$, that is, $a^3 \equiv b^3 \bmod 10$.

Now, $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection mod $10$. Therefore, $a^3 \equiv b^3 \bmod 10$ implies $a \equiv b \bmod 10$.

Then $a^2+ab+b^2 \equiv 3a^2$ implies $10 \mid a$ and so $10 \mid b$.

Therefore, $1000 \mid a^3$ and $1000 \mid b^3$, hence $1000 \mid (a^3-b^3)$.

Comment: "$x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection mod $10$. Therefore, $a \equiv b \bmod 10$." Can you explain?

Comment: How does the fact that it is a bijection allow you to take the cubic root?

Comment: @user19405892, use that the map is *injective*.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more general result:

> Let $\Psi_n(x,y)$ denote the $n$th homogenized [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). If $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, every prime divisor of $\Psi_n(x,y)$ is either:
>
> - $1\pmod n$
> - a prime divisor of $n$
> - a prime divisor of both $x$ and $y$

This is a simple corollary of the same result for the usual cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)=\Psi_n(x,1)$ (where the third case doesn't occur).

In our case $2\mid\Psi_3(a,b)=a^2+ab+b^2$. As $3\nmid2$ and $2\not\equiv1\pmod3$, we have $2\mid a,b$. Same argument for $5$.

---

Entirely self-contained proof of that result in the case of prime $n$ (here $n=3$):

We then have $\Psi_n(x,y)=x^{n-1}+xy^{n-2}+\cdots+y^{n-1}$. Let $p\mid\Psi_n(x,y)\mid x^n-y^n$. If $p\mid x$ or $y$, we are done. If not, $y$ is invertible mod $p$, and $(x/y)^n\equiv1$. Let $k$ be the order of $x/y$ mod $p$. $k\mid n$.
If $k=1$, $x\equiv y$ and $p\mid x^{n-1}+xy^{n-2}+\cdots+y^{n-1}\equiv nx^{n-1}$, so $p\mid n$, so $p=n$.
If $k=n$, $n\mid p-1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Could you also give an elementary proof of the result?

Comment: An good reference is http://www.yimin-ge.com/doc/cyclotomic_polynomials.pdf, but we can repeat the argument in this special case without using all those properties of cyc pol's: Let $p\mid a^2+ab+b^2\mid a^3-b^3$. If $p\nmid a,b$, then $b$ (and $a$) is invertible mod $p$ and $p\mid(a/b)^3-1$. Let $k$ be the order of $a/b$ mod $p$. Then $k\mid3$. If $k=1$, $a/b\equiv1$ so $a\equiv b$, so $p\mid a^2+ab+b^2\equiv3a^2$, so $p\mid 3$. If $k=3$, $3\mid p-1$ by Fermat.

Comment: FYI, an interesting application of that (elementary) result is: for all $n$, there are infinitely many primes $\equiv1\mod n$. (If there were finitely many, let $x$ be their product, contradiction by considering $\Psi_n(x,1)$.)

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $a^2+ab+b^2$ has to be even $\implies a,b$ both must be even(why?)

WLOG $a=2A,b=2B$

Now as $10|(a^2+ab+b^2),5|(a^2+ab+b^2)$

$$a^2+ab+b^2=(A+2B)^2+3A^2\implies(A+2B)^2\equiv-3A^2\pmod5$$

Again, for any integer $r,r\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2\pmod5\implies r^2\equiv0,\pm1$

$\implies(A+2B)^2\equiv0,\pm3\pmod5$ which is only possible if $5|(A+2B)$

$\implies5|B^2\implies5|B$ and $\implies5|(A+2B)\implies5|A$

Comment: @Joffan Expand the RHS and you get $4A^2+4AB+4B^2$; now use $a=2A$, $b=2B$. More interesting is: how to come up with rewriting it this way? It's called [Completing the Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)